# Align items in dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a dropdown. I want the dropdown menu to be always divided into two columns and can take up several lines.
My problem is that the columns are not at the same level, that is, there is a difference between the positions.

Does anyone know how I can align all the elements of my dropdown menu?

Thanks.

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r76w7q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <div *ngFor="let menu of ArrayMenu">
    <div *ngIf="menu.sons == true">
      <div class="dropright">
        <div class="myListGroup" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/png;base64,{{menu.icon}}">
          <span>{{menu.desc}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu mydropdown">
          <div *ngFor="let item of ArrayMenu">
            <div *ngIf="item.idMenu == menu.id" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 8px;">
              <div class="divFilhos">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/png;base64,{{item.icon}}">
                <span>{{item.desc}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

**Problem**

[image]

Comment: Something weird in the structure, the Product item stays on top, but empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing gap on top of the 2nd column because of flowing property of column. You can avoid it by adding 'display-inline-block' to the child element. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-piqvbv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<div *ngIf="item.idMenu == menu.id" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 8px; display: inline-block;">
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `HTML` you have given `margin` to the items, change it to `padding`.

```
<div *ngIf="item.idMenu == menu.id" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;padding: 8px;">
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dpeyyi?file=src/app/app.component.html)